# rest api express update a field

Tags: javascript, rest, express

I try to update a field in my collectionObject.
This is my attempt, but not working. My get api for a specific item does work.

```
  app.put('/api/beers/:id/comment', (req,res) =>{



    Beer.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, function(err, beer){
        beer.name='newName';

    });
});
```

can someone explain me, why it's not working?
Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format for `findByIdAndUpdate`

```
findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options, callback)
```

You are not providing any update object. That's why it's not updating.

Try something like

```
 Beer.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {name : 'updatedName'},...
```